# Is it possible to access the Spring Application Context without implementing ApplicationContextAware?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I am debugging a Java application which uses the Spring IoC Container. I have a breakpoint set in one of the methods of a class annotated as a `@Component`. I would like to get my hands on the Spring Application Context which manages this bean (to access some different bean, which hasn't been injected into this class).

Since I don't want to modify the code, implementing ApplicationContextAware is out of question. 
How could I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Simply add a field of the type `ApplicationContext` and annotate it with @Autowired. You cannot have access to it if you don't modify the class.

Comment: Are you sure there's no other way? Via some singleton?

Comment: You can try the `ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext` but that only works in a web application and will only give you the root application context (the one loaded with the `ContextLoaderListener`). But either way you still have to modify your code to get access to the `ApplicationContext`. But why mess around with the `ApplicationContext` instead of wiring the dependencies?!

Comment: Suppose that I cannot modify the code and would just like to quickly check some property/setting in a different bean.

Comment: Really don't understand what you're asking.  Without modifying *any* code?  Do you mean you want to browse around within your debugger and view the in memory state of objects that aren't referenced in the current thread's callstack?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I would like to open the "Display" window in Eclipse and run something like `ApplicationContext.getInstance().getBean("someBean")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, no need to implement ApplicationContextAware.

You can @Autowire the application context

```
private @Autowired ApplicationContext appContext;
```

**EDIT**

without any code modification, what you need is a good profiling tool. Maybe[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) can do the trick, or some free alternative.

Comment: Nice try, but that's what I want to avoid (code modification).

Comment: Ok. Without modify something, I don't think it is possible. Let me know if you can modify/add some code or class.